# is there any way to change the caption of buttons from capital letters to small letters, in materializedcss?

Tags: materialize

I'm using materialized css to design my personal website. when I use the button, its caption is always shown in capital letters. I tried to change it but failed to do so. can anyone help me out with this, please?

Comment: You could simply over-ride the CSS style responsible for the UPPERCASE text transform?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Trung.

Answer (score 37):

Add this to your css

```
.btn {
    text-transform: unset !important;
}
```

or if you want to change it for specific buttons only, add this to your css :

```
.no-uppercase {
     text-transform: unset !important;
}
```

then just add `no-uppercase` to the desired buttons' classes.

---

Updated to newer syntax thanks to @ziganotschka

Answer (score 6):

### There has been a syntax change

- This syntax is deprecated now:

```
.btn {
  text-transform: none !important;
}
```

- The following syntax is now to be used (as of 02-02-2021):

```
.btn {
  text-transform: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference? :D

Comment: Has a typo, thanks for pointing out! `none` needs to be replaced by `unset`.

Comment: I was just about to give up on the button tag and go with a instead... until I saw your comment. So I can confirm it works btw, the new syntax, so thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-none`:

```
<v-btn class="text-none">Your Text</v-btn>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes can you just need to css in Button tag like below

```
<Button style={{color:'white',textTransform:'none'}}>Home</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn {
  text-transform: initial !important;
}

If you use Vuetify, can follow the following.

.btn span.v-btn__content{
  text-transform: initial !important;
}
```

Looking forward to helping you.

Answer (score -1):

you have to override the button class in your css file like below

```
span.MuiButton-label {
 text-transform: none;
 font-family: sans-serif !important; //change any font style
}
```